# How to perform OnClientClick before OnClick?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have button with `OnClick` event and `OnClientClick`, inside of `listView`. The `onClientClick` have JS function confirm('sure??'). The confirmation message should appear before postback upon specific condition. How to perform that `onClientClick` depending on the condition inside the listview `itemDataBound()`?

Code:

```
protected void lvCo_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e){
int Req = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCoId")).Text);

if (Req==5)
   // Show Confirmation Message 
else
   // Don't Show the Confirmation Message
}
```

aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvCo" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CoId"                    OnItemCommand="lvCoFind_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="lvCo_ItemDataBound">
   // .. Layouttemplate .. && Itemtemplate

    <asp:Button Text="Save" ID="btSaveOp" CommandName="Save"  runat="server" OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" />
```

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: What is the code? I don't understand what part of this you're having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry for the weakness question, I'll copy the code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible, but how about moving the onclientclick out of the aspx page and just setting it in the code behind.

```
protected void lvCo_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e){
int Req = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCoId")).Text);

if (Req==5) // Show Confirmation Message 
   ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btSaveOp")).OnClientClick = "if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;";
```